# Equivalent of DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved with MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers, dom-node

I currently have the code:

```
$('.example').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
    ....
});
```

Which works perfectly but it is not very efficient and has since deprecated. What is a better way to do this?

I have been looking into MutationObserver but this code does work?

It is giving the error "`mutation.addedNodes` is not a function" I would also need the `removedNodes` I realise.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
          if (node.className == 'example') {
              ....
          }
        });
      });
    });
    observer.observe(document, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      attributes: false,
      characterData: false,
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.addedNodes` returns a `NodeList` not an `Array` , that does not have `.forEach()` method. Try using `Array.prototype.slice()` to cast `.addedNodes` to an `Array` which has method `.forEach()`

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(mutation.addedNodes);
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
          if (node.parentElement.className == "example") {
              alert(node.parentElement.className)
          }
        });
      });
    });
    observer.observe(document.querySelector(".example"), {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      attributes: false,
      characterData: false,
    });

var el = document.createElement("div");
el.className = "example-child";
document.querySelector(".example").appendChild(el)
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```

Comment: Wait I need `document` to be `.example`? because I want to be notified of any child node of `.example` rather than `.example` itself

Comment: @Maximilian _"Wait I need document to be .example? because I want to be notified of any child node of .example rather than .example itself "_ Yes

Comment: @Maximilian _"This just doesn't seem to work!"_ Can describe "doesn't seem to work" ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net , or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: There is a difference in a behaviour: *DOMNodeRemoved* not fired for observed node. Should I use a parent? *MutationObserver* seems useless to me (

Comment: @DenisKolodin _"There is a difference in a behaviour: DOMNodeRemoved not fired for observed node."_ Have you posted a Question describing issue? Can you share a plnkr http://plnkr.co demonstrate issue?

Comment: @guest271314 Hasn't plnkr, but this code: https://github.com/DenisKolodin/elm-ace/blob/master/src/Native/Ace.js#L94

Comment: Not certain what expected result of linked `javascript` is? Can you reproduce issue at plnkr or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle? Have you asked a Question including [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?